# How to avoid duplicate code in the translation objects?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, superclass

I have a super class named Transformer. and I have two derived classes that converts class A to B and vice versa. There is the classes :

```
class A{
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    ... getter and setters
}

class B{
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    ... getter and setters
}

interface Transformer<S,D> {
    D convert(S source);
}

class ATransformer implements Transformer<A,B>{
    public B convert(A a){
        B b=new B();
        b.setId(a.getId());
        .....
        return b;
    }
}

class BTransformer implements Transformer<B,A>{
    public A convert(B b){
        A a=new A();
        a.setId(b.getId());
        .....
        return a;
    }
}
```

as you see, derived transformer classes have duplicate codes. Is there any design or solution to avoid this duplication without using reflection?

Comment: It seems you don't need multiple classes.

Comment: What is the difference between A and B other than the classname?

Comment: @cricket_007 for example A is my entity and B is my dto

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bean mapper framework like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika) to do the work for you (and spare you the duplicate code).
However as already mentioned in the other comments, it is (in most cases) preferable to avoid having classes that are nearly the same without them being in the same class hirarchy and therefore castable.

Comment: No, orika uses byte code generation - No reflection needed